# Where to put index.html in a Kotlin-js project?

Tags: javascript, maven, kotlin

I'm testing out compiling Kotlin to JavaScript with Maven. I successfuly compiled it to .js files and now I'm looking for a way to generate a working example launched from HTML file. Is there a way to achive that with Maven?

Similar functionality, I think, is present in Intellj plugin.

Comment: Did you take a look at the browser examples under https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/master/libraries/examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to apply `war` packaging. Configure `maven-war-plugin` to use additional resource directory and `kotlin-maven-plugin` to put `js` file into this directory, i.e.:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
      <webResources>
        <resource>
          <directory>${project.build.directory}/kotlin-js/</directory>
        </resource>
      </webResources>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
      <phase>compile</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>js</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <output>${project.build.directory}/kotlin-js/</output>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </plugin>
```

as for `index.html` it's simple: put it into `src/main/webapp/`

Comment: If you don't want war file, you can use `maven-assembly-plugin`, but `maven-war-plugin` is recognized by all major IDEs, so you won't even need to configure your IDE to put `html` file to a corresponding location.

Comment: Also, you won't need to rebuild Maven project every time. IDE configures itself from Maven and will always copy generated JS file to corresponding directory in servlet container.